# C++ template/aliasing - Type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-aliasing

I'm getting my feet wet with aliasing in templated classes, and haven't been able to compile the following code:

```
template <class T> using item_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;
class Container
{
    std::vector<item_ptr> list;
};
```

I get two compile errors, `a type-value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list`, and a `template argument 2 is invalid.` However, if I write the following code instead:

```
template <class T> //using item_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;
class Container
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> list;
};
```

then it compiles without errors. According to my understanding, these two statements should do the same thing. What am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `item_ptr` is still a template so you need `item_ptr<T>` just like you do with `shared_ptr<T>`

Comment: _"According to my understanding, these two statements should do the same thing."_ - Then why do you use them differently? You provide a template parameter to `std::shared_ptr<T>`, but not to `item_ptr` ;)

Comment: How could the compiler possibly know what type of `item_ptr` you want to instantiate in `Container`, when you don't tell it? I don't know that this is a typo, but it sure is a thinko. Did you perhaps mean something like `using item_ptr = std::shared_ptr<SomeItemClass>`?

Comment: @underscore_d Isn't `item_ptr` just a `shared_ptr` to a `T` object now? So couldn't `item_ptr` only be of type `T`?

Comment: @JaromAllen The `template <class T>` only applies to the `using` alias declaration. It doesn't apply to the `Container`. Not that just `vector<item_ptr>` would be valid even if the `Container` did have a `template` line. They _both_ need those, and the usage of the alias must provide any template arguments it requires. @bipll already showed this

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
template <class T> using item_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;

template <class T> class Container
{
    std::vector<item_ptr<T>> list;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use aliasing in the class, then define in the class:

```
template<class T>
class Container
{    
     using item_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;        
     std::vector<item_ptr> list;  
   
};
```